# placing a StaggeredGridView inside a scrollview in android

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, staggered-gridview

In my application i am using StaggeredGridView and it is working fine. But when i placed it inside a scorllview and try to scroll it unfortunately the height of the StaggeredGridView is not matching with the exact grid view.

For controlling the scroll i am dynamically caluculating the height of the gridview and setting it to the gridview programatically by Based On Children items. i think it will be the problem..

here the main problem is item heights will be not same like normal gridview.

Here is my code for setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(StaggeredGridView listView) {

SampleAdapter listAdapter = (SampleAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
if (listAdapter == null)
    return;

int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int totalHeight = 0;
View view = null;

for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
    if (i == 0)
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
}

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));

listView.setLayoutParams(params);
listView.requestLayout();
  }
```

Can any one help me out to placed a StaggeredGridView  inside a scroll view..
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @SagarZala unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code with passing no of column :

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(StaggeredGridView staggeredGridView, int columns) {
        SampleAdapter listAdapter = (SampleAdapter) staggeredGridView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int items = listAdapter.getCount();
        int rows = 0;

        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(0, null, staggeredGridView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        float x = 1;
        if( items > columns ){
            x = items/columns;
            rows = (int) (x + 1);
            totalHeight *= rows;
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight;
        gridView.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

Comment: not working.. it just showing a small grid view as it having more than 20 items also